# Basic Animation effect - should I use jQuery or HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm currently working on a very basic animation for my web page at the moment.

1. I'd like to move one element (*.item1*) from the bottom into a container.
2. Once this move is completed, I would like to move a 2nd item (*.item2*) from the left into the middle of the container.

In time, these div blocks will be replaced with images.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9rE6Z/3/embedded/result/

What would be the best approach to doing this?
Is it possible to use jQuery or should I be looking at HTML5 Canvas for this?

I'm very new to both areas and would really appreciate some pointers with this :-)

Many thanks :-D

**My HTML:**

```
<div style="width:100%;background:white">

    <div style="height:450px;width:980px;margin:0 auto;background:white;border:1px solid #000">

    </div>

</div>

<div class="item1" style="position:absolute;top:450px;left:50%;width:100px;height:100px;background:black"></div><!-- ease this up from bottom -->
<div class="item2" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100px;height:100px;background:blue"></div><!-- ease this in from left -->
```

Comment: Did you read about [jQuery `animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)? It should be very easy with it.

Comment: Given your scope of basic animation, jQuery would be fine as well as it is easier to use (in my opinion) than manipulating a canvas. Also allows better cross-compatibility.

Comment: you better go with jquery, jquery will handle browsers compatibility.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. I'm very new to jQuery. Do you have examples of how I would go around doing this?

Comment: Just edit your question into "animating with jQuery", and ask how you should do this with jQuery. Also, please provide a new fiddle with the styles in the CSS window, and NOT inline.

Comment: Thank you, Bram. I'll do this right now. Really appreciate all the comments so far. jQuery it is :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9rE6Z/4/

```
var i1 = $("#item1"),
    i2 = $("#item2"),
    wrap = $("#wrap");

i1.animate({
    "bottom": 0,
    "opacity": 1
}, 700, function () {
    i2.animate({
        "left": 0,
        "opacity": 1
    }, 700);
});
```

I changed your HTML mark up a bit, too make it more logical.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="inner-wrap">
        <div id="item1"></div>
        <div id="item2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. That was absolutely perfect!! My sincere apologies for the delayed reply, I didn't see the 'Answer' link :-)